# Magento 2 brocken css on frontend backend

Tags: magento2

i have installed a lattest magento 2.3.5 but my css are brocken as am getting this.

Comment: You run all commands ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your magento `<root>app/etc/di.xml`
and change the following line:

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

To:

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an order for installation.
Please check this steps.

```
composer install
```

php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://3.7.242.09/public/new/" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento13" --db-user="magento" --db-password="Ics@2020" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="dpop006@gmail.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="1532587Adova" --language="en_US" --currency="USD" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin"

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento config:set dev/static/sign 0
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
sudo chmod -R 0777 var/ pub/ generated/